# Clarification of definition tangent space.

Tags: differential-geometry, tangent-spaces

I read that the tangent space $T_p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ at $p$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the vector space of all arrows emanating in $p$.

Does this mean that we $p$ is the origin in $T_p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and that we can identify $T_p( \mathbb{R}^n) \cong \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$?

I think this is geometrically more clear in my head but don't know how to make it formal.

Comment: If you have a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ at $p$, then it has $n$ components. If we view tangent vectors this way, then you can see that $T_p\mathbb{R}^n\cong\mathbb{R}^n.$

Comment: Yes, I was confused because I was thinking about the plane tangent to a sphere, but here there are more directions.

Comment: FYI, we naturally view the sphere as sitting in $\mathbb{R}^3,$ but it's actually a $2$-dimensional manifold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in this interpretation of the tangent space, we place the origin at $p$. But the dimension doesn't decrease, so we have $T_p(\Bbb R^n)\cong \Bbb R^n$. (Consider $T_0(\Bbb R^n)$ for simplicity. There are $n$ full dimensions of vectors to choose from.)

Yes, a surface in $\Bbb R^3$ will have an $\Bbb R^2$ tangent space at each point, but that's not what this is about. This is about $\Bbb R^n$ itself being the manifold we study.